# visual studio xamarin error

Tags: android, visual-studio

I am creating an app in VS 2015 using Xamarin and when running it I get this error
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/food" />
```

I have the Food.jpg in the drawable folder as it shows up in VS when I select design.

Thanks

Comment: What is the code that's throwing the exception?

Comment: it only saysAndroid.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout